# Is it a bad idea to make roaming profile share available offline?

Tags: windows, active-directory, roaming-profile, folder-redirection, offline-files

This is regarding a Windows 2008 R2 domain. The Documents, Desktop, Application Data folders are all redirected to users' home directory (mapped as Z:). The users home directory is configured to be offline for mobile users.

User profiles are configured as roaming, and located on a separate share (not mapped as a network drive), just accessed via an UNC path.

Would it be a good or idea to make the roaming profile share available offline for mobile users using the caching option "All files and programs that users open from the share will be automatically available offline"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not a good idea. Microsoft's recommendation is to not enable offline files for roaming profiles.

Comment: Thanks. For anyone else interested, I found a link to back that up. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736881(WS.10).aspx